# Create new key based on relationship between two columns

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I'm trying to add a key for all related instances between two columns, then create a GroupID

The logic will be:

1. Check all instances of ID2 linked to ID1
2. CHeck all instances of ID1 linked to ID2 found in (1)
3. Repeat until all relationships found

[image]

Comment: Can you show the table ? not the pic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us try with `networkx`

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'ID1', 'ID2')
l=list(nx.connected_components(G))
L=[dict.fromkeys(y,x) for x, y in enumerate(l)]
d={k: v for d in L for k, v in d.items()}
df['new'] = df['ID1'].map(d)
df
Out[302]: 
  ID1  ID2  new
0   A    1    0
1   A    2    0
2   B    1    0
3   B    3    0
4   C    4    1
5   C    5    1
6   D    2    0
```

Comment: Wow, that was super quick, thank you. I've been struggling for hours with networkx and wasn't sure if it would work as there are instance of multiple edges to a single node.